# Multiple Files Open in XCode 6

Tags: xcode

I am a long time Visual Studio and Eclipse user, and now that I'm developing iPhone applications, I've need to use XCode 6. Does anyone know how to do these two really (seemingly) easy things in XCode 6:

- **Close an open file:** There's no apparent button to close a source file once you've opened it. So, now I have a ton of open files that I don't know how to close.
- **Use tabs:** If I have a bunch of files open, I've only been able to successfully switch between them by using the little left and right arrows by the file's breadcrumb.

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but my brain is wired in a completely different direction than Apple thinks it should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Close an open file: File > Close Window or File > Close Tab
- Use tabs: File > New > Tab

Comment: That was so helpful. Thank you. Is there a way, like in VS and Eclipse, to have new source files open up in their own tabs?

Comment: See Preferences > Navigation.